# estimated posteriors in JAGS by levels of a factor

Tags: jags

I am running an N-mixture model in JAGS, trying to see if posterior predicted values of N are higher in one habitat than another. I am wondering how to obtain posterior probabilities of estimated population size for each habitat individually after running the model. So, e.g., if I wanted to sum across all sites, I'd put
totalN<-sum(N[]) in the JAGS model and identify "totalN" as one of my parameters. If I have 2 habitat levels over which to sum N, do I need a for loop or is there another way to define it?

Below is my model so far...

model{

## priors

```
#abundance
beta0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)     # log(lambda) intercept
beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.001) #this is my regression parameter for habitat
tau.T ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001) #this is for random effect of transect

# detection
alpha.p ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
beta.p ~ dgamma (0.01, 0.01)
```

## Poisson model for abundance

```
for (i in 1:nsite){
loglam[i] <- beta1*habitat[i] + ranef[transect[i]]
loglam.lim[i] <- min(250, max(-250, loglam[i]))  # 'Stabilize' log 
lam[i] <- exp(loglam.lim[i])
N[i] ~ dpois(lam[i])
}
for (i in 1:14){
ranef[i]~dnorm(beta0,tau.T)
}
```

## Measurement error model

```
for (i in 1:nsite){
for (j in 1:nrep){
y[i,j] ~ dbin(p[i,j], N[i])
p[i,j] ~ dbeta(alpha.p,beta.p) #detection probability follows a beta distribution
}
}
```

## posterior predictions

```
Nperhabitat<-sum(N[habitat]) #this doesn't work, only estimates a single set of posterior densities for N
#and get a derived detection probability

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume here that `habitat` is a binary vector. I would add two additional vectors to your data that define which elements in `habitat` are 1 and which are 0. From there you can index `N` with those two vectors.

```
# done in R and added to the data list supplied to JAGS
hab_1 <- which(habitat == 1)
hab_0 <- which(habitat == 0)

# add to data list
data_list <- list(..., hab_1 = hab_1, hab_0 = hab_0)
```

Then, inside the `JAGS` model you would just add:

```
N_habitat_1 <- sum(N[hab_1])
N_habitat_0 <- sum(N[hab_0])
```

This is effectively telling `JAGS` to provide the total abundance per habitat type. If you have way more sites of one habitat vs another this abundance may hide that the density of individuals could actually be less. Thus, you may want to divide this abundance by the total number of sites of each habitat type:

```
dens_habitat_1 <- sum(N[hab_1]) / sum(habitat)
dens_habitat_0 <- sum(N[hab_0]) / sum(1 - habitat)
```

This is, of course, assuming that `habitat` is binary.

Comment: Thanks, M_Fidino! Habitat is indeed binary and I liked this possibility, but which(habitat==x) seems to just identify the components of the habitat vector that are either 0 or 1. I have 35 0s and 35 1s, so that then becomes hab0 = 1...35 and hab1 = 36...70. Because there are then 35 unique values for each habitat, no posteriors are predicted, and I get the following error from mcmcplots: e.g.,  hab_0[1]. Error in bw.SJ(x, method = "ste"): sample is too sparse to find TD. It seems like I would have to somehow link habitat itself to hab_1 and hab_0 in the JAGS model?

Comment: That is exactly what the which statement should provide. You want to track `N_habitat_1` as a parameter and `N_habitat_0`, not `hab_0` and `hab_1`. The latter two are data supplied to the model while the former two are the summed abundance in the first 35 sites (hab = 1) and the last 35 sites (hab = 0).